# Forbidden: 403 Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied while getting Drive credentials

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I've created a table linked to Google Sheet in Big Query. This sheet has an apps script to invoke a Cloud Function query the table and creates a new table
The queries are working fine but when I trigger the apps script I received the message access denied from the cloud function.

**UPDATE**

- The cloud function service and the appscript are in the same Google
  Cloud Project
- I've added allUsers to the CF invoker
- I`ve also share the gsheet with the account service email
- I`ve enabled Google Drive API under 'Services', added
  DriveApp.getRootFolder(); at the beginning of my apps script and
  edited the scope

but I still get the message above

Here is my code

```
DriveApp.getRootFolder();
function onEdit(e) {
  var url = 'myCloudFunctionURL'; 
  var range = e.range;
  if (range.getColumn() == 1) { // Check if edited cell is in column A
    var word = range.getValue();

    var payload = {
      "variable": word, // Use the retrieved value as the payload data
    };
    
    var options = {
      'method' : 'post',
      'contentType': 'application/json',
      'payload' : JSON.stringify(payload)
    };
    
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    Logger.log(response.getContentText());
  }
}
```

JSON:

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [
      {
        "userSymbol": "Drive",
        "version": "v2",
        "serviceId": "drive"
      }
    ]
    
  },
  "oauthScopes": [
          "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly",
          "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
          "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly",
          "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
        ],
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: This question contains no diagnostically useful information. Saying *an apps script generates a Cloud Function error* is meaningless. You must include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question containing the context of the error message like its stack trace and the code from your Cloud Function showing where the error was generated. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally what I was missing was declaring in the cloud function de Oauth scope to enable Drive access: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-drive?hl=es-419#python_3

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons why you are encountering this error but here are some of the resolutions that you can validate if it will solve your problem.

1. Assuming that you have created them all correctly, You need to deploy again your cloud function after creating the appscript otherwise it will not validate the Client ID.
2. You need to add allUsers to your cloud function invokers under cloud function permissions and you might need to allow the public access.
3. You need to make sure that the cloud function service and the appscript are in the same Google Cloud Project.
4. You need to add a scope to manifest. For example in the GCP documentation:

> Setting scopes explicitly is sometimes required for certain applications like add-ons, since published applications should always use the narrowest scopes possible.

```
{
        ...
        "oauthScopes": [
          "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly",
          "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
        ],
       ...
      }
```

You can learn more about the scope and manifests using these documentations:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/manifests

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes

Comment: Thank you. I've followed the steps and the error persisted. Then I followed the indications here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69583290/permission-denied-while-getting-drive-credentials-error-occurs-when-accessing?rq=1 but now I receive the following message from apss acript: Exception: You do not have permission to call DriveApp.getRootFolder. Required permissions: (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly || https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive)

Comment: The account does not have the right permissions to perform the action, try attaching the right roles needed in the OAuth scope. 

Here is a guide on how to add it. 
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/js In the example, there is a given for OAuth. const SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly', you also need to add it to your script for authentication. 
Here is a reference of the roles and permissions for drive: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#drivev3

Comment: I think I don´t fully understand your suggestion. I`ve checked the reference and added https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform to the scope but the message persists when it triggers the cloud function